# fetch the data dynamically from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, media-player

```
<Point  TestFlag="0" id="1" name="Session Introduction">
        <PracticeText> </PracticeText>
        <PracticeFlag> 0 </PracticeFlag>
        <ImageFile gid="1" id="1" name="d002_p001_01" type="png" />
        <AudioFile gid="1" id="2" name="d002_ae_p001.mp3" type="mp3" />
        </Point>

<Point  TestFlag="0" id="1" name="Conversation Introduction">
        <PracticeText> </PracticeText>
        <PracticeFlag> 0 </PracticeFlag>
        <ImageFile gid="1" id="1" name="d002_p001_02" type="png" />
        <AudioFile gid="1" id="2" name="d002_ae_p002.mp3" type="mp3" />
        </Point>

<Point  TestFlag="0" id="1" name="Dialogue sets">
        <PracticeText> </PracticeText>
        <PracticeFlag> 0 </PracticeFlag>

        <ImageFile gid="1" id="1" name="d002_p001_01" type="png" />
        <AudioFile gid="1" id="2" name="d002_ae_p001.mp3" type="mp3" />

            <ImageFile gid="1" id="1" name="d002_p001_02" type="png" />
            <AudioFile gid="1" id="2" name="d002_ae_p002.mp3" type="mp3" />
        </Point>
```

what i basically doing here is i am playing the audio files and displaying the images from the xml which are in `AudioFile` and `ImageFile` tag, but first two point i am playing when the user clicks on next button based on the i value.But when it comes to third point i am playing the 2 audio and 2 images continuously.

For playing audio files continuously i am using oncompletion listener.

My problem is 
1.I want it do be dynamically acheived.
2.Suppose if we are able to acheive dynamically when in the future one or two more points is inserted in the middle of these three points also it should work

how to do this please help i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for get the length of each child tag of one point

try this this might help you

```
NodeList image = doc.getElementsByTagName("Point");
            Element firstLevel = (Element)singleTerminalNode;
        NodeList value1Nodes = (firstLevel).getElementsByTagName("ImageFile");
        lengthofimage = value1Nodes.getLength();
```